# Passing a variable to setTimeout()

Tags: drupal, settimeout, jcarousel

I've installed a Jcarousel on Drupal 7 but I need it to scroll horizontally to both sides when the client hovers over the arrows.

I've been trying to pass a variable to the Timeout function and it doesn't seem to work. 
In the following code Timeout recognizes only: var n = function () {c.next();};
I need to be able to tell timeout to either scroll left or right using c.prev() or c.next() depending on which arrow the user clicked.

```
var c = this;
var k = 1;
var n = function () {c.next();};

if (k == 1) n = function () {c.prev();};
if (k == 5) n = function () {c.next();};

this.timer = window.setTimeout(n, 500)
```

I've also tried to do it this way and it doesn't work either.

```
var c = this;
var k = 5;
this.timer = window.setTimeout(function() {c.nextprev(k);}, 500)
```

...

```
  nextprev: function(k) {

if (k === 1) return "prev()";
if (k === 5) return "next()";

}
```

Any help or guideline will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it doesn't feel 100% right, but introduces some techniques you seem to need:

c.nextprev to execute immediately and return a function that will do what was really needed, capturing c and k as a closure...

```
c.nextprev = function(k){ 
  return function(){
// I feel like prev and next might be backwards... think about that
    if (k === 1) c.prev();  
    if (k === 5) c.next();
// do nothing if k not 1 nor 5
 }
};

c.timer = window.setTimeout(c.nextprev(k), 500);
```

...or maybe just do this without all the preceding code....

Here bind sets "this" back to c.

```
setTimeout( (k === 5)? c.next.bind(c): ((k === 1)? c.prev.bind(c): function(){} ) );
```

Comment: Exactly that is what I did after trying your first answer. And it doesn't work either. I've been going around and around with this during a couple of days now. Maybe I'm on the wrong path and the problem is somewhere else in Jcarousel's code.